# How to build a web based chat application similar to gmail using java at backend logic

Tags: java

Hii,
      I want to built a web based chat using j2ee at backend logic.i want to implement the similar way the gmail do,so that performance of application doesnr degrade.please suggest what type of architecture shoul i follow.load of application would be high.

Answer (score 0):

Use what Google used: [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/). They spent years on making it fast and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

The Jetty web container has a demo chat application which uses Ajax as the gmail chat does and which is not *too* complicated to learn.

It appears somebody has a Jetty running on http://64.164.6.244:9090/test/chat/chat.html, so you can see what it looks like before downloading and running it yourself.